# Error calling "fulfill" from closure

Tags: swift, storekit, promisekit

Here's my error...

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x18)

Here is my product request delegate...

```
class ProductRequestDelegate : NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    private var products: ([SKProduct]) -> Void

    init(products: @escaping ([SKProduct]) -> Void) {

        self.products = products
    }

    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

        products(response.products)
    }

    public func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {

    }
}
```

Here is the request...

```
fileprivate var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest?

public func getProducts() -> Promise<Set<SKProduct>> {

        return Promise { fulfill, reject in

            productsRequest?.cancel()

            productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers)

            productsRequest!.delegate = ProductRequestDelegate { products in

                self.productsRequest = nil

                fulfill(Set(products))
            }

            productsRequest!.start()
        }
    }
```

This call results in the error occurring...

```
_ = iAPHelper.getProducts()
```

Any ideas why this should not work? It seems that the delegate is deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate property on `SKProductsRequest` is `unowned(unsafe)`, so the object assigned to it is deallocated. (Instruments informed me of the deallocation after switching on zombies.)

So, I added a reference to the delegate to the class which contains the function `getProducts()`. And it works.